# android kotlin app not parsing data with retrofit from laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, kotlin, retrofit2

I have to parse data from db table with laravel api and retrofit on android app and then show them in markers on google map..google maps working fine and also function for showing markers but i can not get data from db to List.in ssh server there i have two repositories and drienik repository is where I have Laravel folder with laravel api .. below is my kotlin code:

This one is retrofit builder:

```
package com.bp.digitalizacia_spravy_ciest

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ServiceBuilder {

   private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

   private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("https://drienik@147.175.204.24")
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
       .client(client)
       .build()

   fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
       return retrofit.create(service)
   }

}
```

This is where I have get request to route in laravel:

```
package com.bp.digitalizacia_spravy_ciest

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import com.bp.digitalizacia_spravy_ciest.Problems as Problems1

interface problemsAPI {
    @GET("/problem")
    fun getProblems(): Call<List<Problems1>>
}
```

This is data class for saving data from get request:

```
package com.bp.digitalizacia_spravy_ciest

import java.math.BigInteger

data class  Problems(var problem_id: BigInteger, var poloha: String, var popis_prolemu: String
                 /*var kategoria_problemu_id: BigInteger, var stav_problemu_id: BigInteger*/)
```

this is activity where i try to get data and show them in map... function enqueue does not even start:

```
 val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(problemsAPI::class.java)
    val call = request.getProblems()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Problems>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Problems>>,
                                response: Response<List<Problems>>
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val problemList: List<Problems?>? = response.body()
            for (i in problemList!!.indices){

                var pos = problemList[i]!!.poloha
                var postSplit = pos.split(",")
                var pos1 = postSplit[0].toDouble()
                var pos2 = postSplit[1].toDouble()
                var id_problemu = problemList[i]!!.problem_id
              /*  var kategoria = problemList[i]!!.kategoria_problemu_id
                var popis = problemList[i]!!.popis_prolemu
                var stav_problemu = problemList[i]!!.stav_problemu_id*/

                Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, "ok $i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                val snippet = String.format(
                    Locale.getDefault(),
                    "Position: Lat: $pos1, Long: $pos2\n " +
                            "id: $id_problemu\n " +
                          /*  "kategoria: $kategoria\n " +
                            "popis: $popis\n " +*/
                            "stav problemu: $stav_problemu\n "
                )

                map.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .title("cestny problem")
                        .position(LatLng(pos1, pos2))
                        .snippet(snippet)
                )

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Problems>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.w("MyTag", "requestFailed", t);
        }
    })
```

There are my routes in web.php... now I just want the last one work:

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Web Routes
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 |
 | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
 | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
 | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
 |
 */

 Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
 });

 $router->post('problem','ProductController@createProduct');   //for creating product

 $router->get('problem/{id}','ProductController@updateProduct'); //for updating product

 $router->post('problem/{id}','ProductController@deleteProduct');  // for deleting product

 $router->get('problem','ProductController@index'); // for retrieving product
```

and finally controller for routes, just for the last one:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Problem;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 use DB;

 class ProblemController extends Controller
 {
     public function createProduct(Request $request){

         $problem = Problem::create($request->all());

         return response()->json($problem);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was in ip... It should contain port number and retrofit now trigger call.enqueue... but it hits onFailure fun with this message err: Unexpected status line:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
```